# How to automate Message Broker?

Tags: messagebroker

Message Broker is a third party app in my project, and deployed on edge browser.
During login, it is asking for authentication through Microsoft Authenticator.
How to start automate.

I am looking for a solution on how to automate 3rd party apps asking for OTP.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to automate apps, asking for OTP to login?